# Using CSS sub types with ASP.Net controls (CSS attribute selectors)

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

I'm trying to change some of my ASP.Net pages to use s and replace some s.

I had some trouble aligning the labels and text boxes and then I found this awesome JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p54SE/

I had no idea that CSS could be used to give specific instructions to a Label and an input[type=text] separately.  I have referred to these as subtypes of CSS, but if you know the correct terminology please inform me.

How would I be able to recreate this with:

```
<div class='label-wrapper'>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Title" Text="Title" />
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Title"  />
</div>
```

I was so certain just changing the name would work, but no luck.

div.label-wrapper > asp:Label {

Comment: CSS attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asp:Label` control produces `span` by default, so use this to target the produced element:

```
div.label-wrapper > span {
    // your styles here
}
```

Furthermore, you can assign a class to the the control to specifically target it:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="yourClass" runat="server" ID="lbl_Title" Text="Title" />
```

CSS:

```
.yourClass {
    //your styles here
}
```

Comment: Span works and the TextBox was correct all along.  I was just assuming it was broken because the label wasn't working.  Thanks this will help me to align everything.

Comment: @StuckOnSimpleThings You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS selector you need is `div.label-wrapper > span`

You are confusing your server side controls and client side HTML. The server side control `<asp:Label />` renders as a `<span>` element. When applying CSS rules, make sure you look at the HTML that is rendered by your ASP.NET application.

### Option 2

You can also add a `CssClass` attribute to your server side control and reference said class directly.

`<asp:Label runat="server" Text="My Label Text" CssClass="label-text" />`

and use the CSS selector

```
.label-text{
  //your rules here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .Net, the `<asp:Label>` will be turned into `<span>` when the server actually parses the HTML. The `<asp:Label>` is part of .Net that automagically inserts the necessary markup for that element. That said, to target that `<span>`, change your CSS selector to `.label-wrapper > span` and that should work better for you.

Comment: <asp:Label> renders as a <span>, not a <label>.